# What is the easiest way to create a HostAndPort-Instance if the hostname is "localhost"?

Tags: java, guava

I want to use the class [HostAndPort](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/net/HostAndPort.html) from guava, to store a host and a port. What is the easiest way to create a valid `HostAndPort`-Instance, if the host is *"localhost"* and not *"127.0.0.1"* ?

It tried [HostSpecifier.isValid(String)](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/net/HostSpecifier.html) to validate the host, before i create a `HostAndPort`-Instance, but it returns `false` for "localhost". So in my case i can't use `HostSpecifier`, except i transform "localhost" to "127.0.0.1".
Is there an other way to validate a host name without a DNS-lookup?

Comment: there's a hosts file in the local system where you set your name/ip resolvers. your localhost will be resolved to 127.0.0.1 unless you override it with something else in the hosts file.

Comment: Do you mean "127.0.0.1" is not necessarily "localhost" ? Is threre some API, that can handle that case?

Comment: yes. look at my answer. you can try it yourself by editing the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts in windows and assign any ip to the localhost and try to ping it and see how it will be resolved if lmhosts lookup is enabled which usually is by default.

Answer (score 2):

`java.net.InetAddress.getByName(String hostname)` is the one. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html

The local address lookups are done via lmhosts on windows if enabled and on linux/unix using name service switch config(`/etc/nsswitch.conf`) in order to check where to lookup first - `files,dns,nis`.... and so on (`man nsswitch.conf`). The java api call will resolve it depending on a system configuration.

EDIT:

you probably want to take a look at this library too 
http://www.xbill.org/dnsjava/

---

hope this helps abit.